# How to create this arrow up in css?

Tags: html, css

How to create this arrow in `css`?

I tried it with css after but nothing works as expected.

```css
div.arrow {
    width: 12vmin;
    height: 12vmin;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    left: 0%;
    top: 0%;   
 }
div.arrow::before {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #fafafa;
  display: block;
  border-color: black;
 }

 
div.arrow:after {
  content: '';
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  top: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-width: 0 .8vmin 0 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #fafafa;
  border-color: black;
  height: 200%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="arrow"></div>
```

Please help.

[image]

Comment: Share your code for getting support

Comment: Refer this https://codepen.io/ivan_pik/pen/wMEZqQ

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/821kq8es/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
div.arrow {
    width: 12vmin;
    height: 12vmin;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    left: 0%;
    top: 0%;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    
 }
div.arrow::before {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-width: .8vmin .8vmin 0 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #fafafa;
  transition: .2s ease;
  display: block;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
  border-color: black;
  transform: scale(.8);
 }

 
div.arrow:after {
  content: '';
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  top: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-width: 0 .8vmin 0 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #fafafa;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
  transition:.2s ease;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border-color: black;
  height: 200%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="arrow"></div>
```

Comment: @pero, made it bit bigger, but you can play around with the css.